# Thread in 2 queues

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a small program to help me learn some multithreading in java, and I'm stuck on how to implement some scenario.

The program simulates a gas station that also has a coffee house in it.
I want to be able to create the following scenario:

- add a person to a gas pump queue.
- at the same time add a person to a cashier queue in the coffee house.
- if the person's turn in the pump queue arrives before the turn in the cashier queue, allow him to choose what to do (stay in cashier queue and quit the pump queue or the other way around).

How can I jump between these 2 states?

So far I have this:

The Person class

```
public class Person implements Runnable {

private GasPump pump;
private Cashier cashier;
...
public void pumpGas() throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {
        pump.addCarToQueue(this);
        wait();
    }

    synchronized (pump) {
        sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000));
        pump.notify();
    }
}

public void buyCoffee() throws InterruptedException {

    synchronized (this) {
        cashier.addCustomerToQueue(this); // standing inline
        wait();
    }

    synchronized (cashier) {
        sleep((long) (Math.random() * 5000)); // paying at cashier
        cashier.notify();
    }
}
...
}
```

The GasPump class

```
public class GasPump implements Runnable {

private Queue<Person> cars;
...
@Override
public void run() {
    while (gasStation.isOpen()) {
        if (!cars.isEmpty()) {
            Car firstCar = cars.poll();
            if (firstCar != null) {
                synchronized (firstCar) {
                    firstCar.notifyAll();
                }
            } else {
                // ?
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

And the Cashier class

```
public class Cashier implements Runnable {

private Queue<Person> customers;
...
@Override
public void run() {
    while(coffeeHouse.isOpen()){
        if(!customers.isEmpty()){
            Car firstCustomer = customers.poll();
            if(firstCustomer != null){
                synchronized (firstCustomer) {
                    firstCustomer.notifyAll();
                }
            }

            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using `wait` and `notify` as it is difficult to use them correctly and efficiently - use the classes from `java.util.concurrent` instead.

What I would do: add two `boolean` flags to your `Person`: `hasPumped` and `hasShopped` - once a person pumps their gas or shops then you set the appropriate flag to `true`.

Replace your `Queues` with `BlockingQueues` (probably the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is appropriate here) - this is a thread-safe queue, and you can call `take` on it in order to block until the queue is non-empty (rather than polling and then sleeping if the queue is empty).  If you prefer to poll and sleep then you may want to use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` instead, though I advise that you use `take` on a `BlockingQueue` instead.

Add a `Person` to the `GasPump` and `Cashier` queues.  When the person is removed from the queue via `take` or `poll`, then check its `hasPumped` or `hasShopped` flag to determine if any additional action is needed, for example if the `Cashier` takes the person and `hasPumped` is true then there's no need to ask the `Person` if they want to continue waiting in the gas queue since they've already finished pumping.

If the person chooses to quit a queue, then call `remove(person)` on the appropriate queue.

When the person finishes pumping gas then put them in the cashier queue if their `hasShopped` flag is false, and likewise put them in the gas queue when they've finished shopping if their `hasPumped` flag is false.

You shouldn't need any `synchronized` blocks or methods with this implementation.

```
public class Person implements Runnable {

    private GasPump pump;
    private Cashier cashier;
    private boolean hasPumped, hasShopped, readyToPump, readyToShop;
    private Thread thread;

    public void run() {
        thread = Thread.getCurrentThread();
        while(!hasPumped && !hasShopped) {
            try {
                readyToPump = false;
                readyToShop = false;
                if (!hasPumped)
                    pumpGas();
                if(!hasShopped)
                    buyCoffee();
                thread.sleep(FOREVER);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // check flags to see what to do next
            }
        }
    }

    public void pumpGas() {
        pump.addCarToQueue(this);
    }

    public void buyCoffee() {
        cashier.addCustomerToQueue(this);
    }

    public void setReadyToPump() {
        readyToPump = true;
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    public void setReadyToShop() {
        readyToShop = true;
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}

public class GasPump implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Person> cars = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (gasStation.isOpen()) {
            Person person = cars.take();
            person.setReadyToPump();
        }
        // clean up persons in queue
    }
}

public class Cashier implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Person> customers = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(coffeeHouse.isOpen()){
            Person person = customers.take();
            person.setReadyToShop();
        }
        // clean up persons in queue
    }
}
```

Comment: should I start the Person thread after I get an object from take() or should the threads all start when inserted to the queues?

Comment: @Yoni Levy The `GasPump`, `Cashier`, and `Person` threads should all start after they're initialized; the `Person` should call `pumpGas` and `buyCoffee` and *then* the `Person` should `sleep` (`pumpGas` and `buyCoffee` should just add the `Person` to the relevant queues, they shouldn't call `wait` or `sleep` or anything like that); the `GasPump` and `Cashier` threads should `interrupt` the `Person` after removing it from its queue in order to wake it up, and the `Person` should then swallow/ignore the resulting exception.

Comment: @Yoni Levy I recommend that you use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to start your `Person` objects; this will cause all of your `Person` objects to share a common thread pool, as opposed to allocating a separate thread for each `Person`

Comment: I played around with your suggestions and got confused very quickly. what do you mean by "then the Person should sleep"? sleep indefinitely? I thought that take() is taking care of that. And where should I put the ThreadPoolExecutor? in GasPump and in Cashier class to handle each queue or somewhere else?

Comment: @Yoni Levy `take` is taking care of the blocking for the `GasPump` and `Cashier` threads, but the `Person` doesn't have a queue to `take` on - therefore it should `sleep` indefinitely until interrupted (in practice it's usually a good idea to have the `Person` `sleep` for a reasonable amount of time, say 5 minutes, and to then log that the thread timed out if it isn't interrupted in that time; the `BlockingQueue` also has a `poll(timeout, timeunit)` method to do the same thing).  The `ThreadPoolExecutor` goes in your main thread (e.g. in the `static void main` method)

Comment: that seems a bit weird making the thread sleep "forever". And the ThreadPoolExecutor accepts 1 BlockingQueue, when I have 2 BlockingQueues. How can 1 ThreadPoolExecutor handles the 2 queues? can you maybe suggest a solution using the synchronized mechanism? I know its outdated but maybe that way I could understand the topic better and work my way up from there.

Comment: @Yoni Levy It's not sleeping forever, it's sleeping until interrupted - the `Person` is added to the gas queue and the store queue, and at that point it doesn't need to do anything else until one of the queues selects it as wakes it up (interrupts it), so it can sleep in the meantime.  The `ThreadPoolExecutor` is called once per `Runnable`, i.e. `executor.execute(gasPump); executor.execute(cashier); executor.execute(person1); execute.execute(person2);` You should probably leave off the executor until you get the queues implemented properly - just use `thread.start()` for now

Comment: @Yoni Levy If you prefer explicit synchronization then you can use something like a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). The `Person` initializes a semaphore with 2 permits, and the gas and cashier threads acquire these permits; the person then `acquires` a permit, which blocks until a permit is available.  The gas and cashier threads then `release` a permit when they retrieve the person from their queues, which wakes up the person. Note that blocking on the semaphore is the same thing as sleeping "forever"

Comment: @Yoni Levy I've edited my answer with a sample implementation

Comment: the sample implementation helped a lot. You've been a great help. Thanks :)